# Sending notification from IntentService is not working?

Tags: java, android, notifications, intentservice

I'm trying to send a notification from an IntentService.
I do get all the logs, but I don't get the notification (Using my galaxy s8 instead of an emulator).

I've tried to extend Service and I have tried to use a scheduler, but both did not work.

Service Code:

```
public class AppService extends IntentService {

    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    public AppService() {
        super("AppService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Log.d("AppService", "Started");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Restore interrupt status.
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        Log.d("AppService", "Sending notification");
        sendNotification("We might have some brand new movies to offer you!");
        Log.d("AppService", "Notification sent");
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Log.d("AppService", "1");
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, Analyze.class), 0);
        Log.d("AppService", "2");
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle("MyCienma")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_500x500_no_edge)
                        .setContentText(msg);
        Log.d("AppService", "3");
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        Log.d("AppService", "4");
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        Log.d("AppService", "5");
    }
}
```

I do get all the Logs, but I don't get any notification.
My project's min version is 21 and my phone is running 26. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just because you have to set the notification channel id after android version 8.0(api 26).

Reference link:[here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-o-how-to-use-notification-channels--cms-28616)

Hope! this will help you.
Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

After API v26 you have to define a NotificationChannel for every notification

```java
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default",
        "YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME",
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    channel.setDescription("YOUR_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DISCRIPTION");
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```